# LoadRunner and terminal services use

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have been asked to use LoadRunner on several PC to generate larger load but I am somehow unable to set it. I know I have to use terminal services.
Could anyone help me on this? Basically just few steps how to set the controller as I have never done this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use terminal services. You need to employ the concept of 'Load Generators' - check out the help pages using this search term but basically you install some software (from the same disk as LR) on the remote boxes and then use a master (Controller) to connect to each one and control it.

Comment: That is it - I have read docs and it says I have to use terminal service to connect the other generators.

Comment: Well, you can try to use terminal services if you like. But I imagine it won't be a very fruitful experience.

Answer (score 0):

So basically someone is asking you to install a copy of the controller on multiple machines in order to produce larger load than what comes with the evaluation license, correct?

If so, then you have two issues at play

- The evaluation license is not for production use
- The person asking you to do this is asking you to pretty much ignore the license.   I would be willing to bet they will throw you under the bus if someone brings the hammer down on your organization for this.

From a terminal server persepective there are pretty severe restrictions on when and where you may use remote desktop to touch a LoadRunner controller.   i.e.  if Controller is in City A and you are in City B, then you're pretty much SOL for using Remote Desktop/Terminal services without (a) violating the license agreement or (b) being within license with the purchase of Performance Center.